# How to get Tomcat JSP servlet app to connect to my CAS server for authentication using java-cas-client?

Tags: jsp, tomcat, single-sign-on, cas, tomcat8.5

I have a tomcat 8.5 server setup on linux and I want users to first authenticate using our CAS server so only people logged in can view the page. How should everything be setup in order to get this to work?

I have gotten all of java-cas-client code compiled and I placed all the jars under $CATALINA_HOME/bin. In $CATALINA_HOME/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/web.xml I have setup the filters using the examples shown. In $CATALINA_HOME/webapps/ROOT/test.jsp I have code that checks "request.getRemoteUser()". But when I got to the webpage, that value is always null. I thought the filter setup would force a login through CAS before showing the webpage. I can tell that tomcat is at least looking at the filter because if I put a typo in the filter name, the server will not startup.

Here is how my web.xml is setup:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                      http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
  version="4.0"
  metadata-complete="true">

    <filter>
        <filter-name>CAS Single Sign Out Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>casServerUrlPrefix</param-name>
            <param-value>https://[MYCASSERVER]/cas</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutHttpSessionListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>CAS Authentication Filter</filter-name>
        <!--<filter-class>org.jasig.cas.client.authentication.Saml11AuthenticationFilter</filter-class>-->
        <filter-class>org.jasig.cas.client.authentication.AuthenticationFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>casServerLoginUrl</param-name>
            <param-value>https://[MYCASSERVER]/cas/login</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>serverName</param-name>
            <param-value>https://[MYAPPSERVER]</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>CAS Validation Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Cas30ProxyReceivingTicketValidationFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>casServerUrlPrefix</param-name>
            <param-value>https://[MYCASSERVER]/cas</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>serverName</param-name>
            <param-value>https://[MYAPPSERVER]</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>redirectAfterValidation</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>useSession</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>authn_method</param-name>
            <param-value>mfa-duo</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>CAS HttpServletRequest Wrapper Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.jasig.cas.client.util.HttpServletRequestWrapperFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CAS Single Sign Out Filter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CAS Validation Filter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CAS Authentication Filter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CAS HttpServletRequest Wrapper Filter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

  <display-name>Welcome to Tomcat</display-name>
  <description>
     Welcome to Tomcat
  </description>

</web-app>
```

And here is my test.jsp code:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" %>
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.Map" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.Iterator" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.List" %>
<%@ page import="org.jasig.cas.client.authentication.AttributePrincipal" %>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>CAS Example Java Web App</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>CAS Example Java Web App</h1>
<p>A sample web application that exercises the CAS protocol features via the Java CAS Client.</p>
<hr>

<p><b>Authenticated User Id:</b> <a href="logout.jsp" title="Click here to log out"><%= request.getRemoteUser() %>
</a></p>

<%
    if (request.getUserPrincipal() != null) {
        AttributePrincipal principal = (AttributePrincipal) request.getUserPrincipal();

        final Map attributes = principal.getAttributes();

        if (attributes != null) {
            Iterator attributeNames = attributes.keySet().iterator();
            out.println("<b>Attributes:</b>");

            if (attributeNames.hasNext()) {
                out.println("<hr><table border='3pt' width='100%'>");
                out.println("<th colspan='2'>Attributes</th>");
                out.println("<tr><td><b>Key</b></td><td><b>Value</b></td></tr>");

                for (; attributeNames.hasNext(); ) {
                    out.println("<tr><td>");
                    String attributeName = (String) attributeNames.next();
                    out.println(attributeName);
                    out.println("</td><td>");
                    final Object attributeValue = attributes.get(attributeName);

                    if (attributeValue instanceof List) {
                        final List values = (List) attributeValue;
                        out.println("<strong>Multi-valued attribute: " + values.size() + "</strong>");
                        out.println("<ul>");
                        for (Object value : values) {
                            out.println("<li>" + value + "</li>");
                        }
                        out.println("</ul>");
                    } else {
                        out.println(attributeValue);
                    }
                    out.println("</td></tr>");
                }
                out.println("</table>");
            } else {
                out.print("No attributes are supplied by the CAS server.</p>");
            }
        } else {
            out.println("<pre>The attribute map is empty. Review your CAS filter configurations.</pre>");
        }
    } else {
        out.println("<pre>The user principal is empty from the request object. Review the wrapper filter configuration.</pre>");
    }
%>

</body>
</html>
```

I expected that when I go to my test.jsp webpage it would first force me to login via my CAS page. But instead the page loads up and says that I am logged in as null, even when I manually go into CAS and log in, it still returns null. I suspect that the filter is either not functioning the way I want (or expect) it to and that I don't understand enough of what filters are supposed to do.

Comment: You may check your localhost logs for error messages. I followed the code example at https://github.com/cas-projects/cas-sample-java-webapp.

Comment: Tomcat doesn't attempt a request to the CAS server and no error message is generated in the log files.